# New Oven in the US, Which would home cooks prefer?

Tags: oven, shopping

I am an English girl living in New York and looking to re-do my kitchen. The most common oven in the US appears to be 30" single space with a warming drawer underneath. In the UK it is a 24" double oven.

Here are my questions:

1. Does anyone use the warming drawer for anything other than storage (esp in the city environment)?
2. If you had a choice would you prefer 30" single space or 24" double space?

Thanks for any help given, want to ensure I design not only for myself but also future tenants given it's a rental :)

Comment: As far as I know, the ovens in the US don't have warming drawers, they have storage drawers. I'm sure they get a bit warm but I don't think they're designed to put food in. Have you been finding ovens with it marketed as a warming drawer instead?

Comment: Living in NYC myself, I have found that in the many apartments I've lived in, I've *always* preferred larger gas ranges with a broiler (either underneath or as part of the unit); convection fans are a bonus. Electric bills tend to be high in NYC, especially in the summer where window A/C is the norm and central A/C is not common. Funds tend to be tight in NYC as well, so they are a welcome relief on the wallet. I have specifically *not* rented apartments because of kitchen appliances that I did not like, electric ranges being one of my top offenders. Just my opinion though.

Comment: Never had or wanted (or even heard of) a warming drawer, by the way. For gas ovens in the US, those drawers underneath are generally broilers, not warming drawers.

Comment: @jefromi, a lot of stoves have a broiler or warmer drawer down below. I **discovered** our broiler drawer wasn't a storage drawer when we cooked some pan's handles. It was a standard GE or Maytag or whatever it was.

Comment: @Escoce Okay maybe not *all* of them are storage-only, but an awful lot are in my experience. It's still a useful partial answer for the OP: obviously a lot of people don't use the warming drawer since a lot of them don't even have one!

Comment: @Jefromi I think that **if** the stove has a broiler or warmer option making it more expensive since it's an option. It's often down there. If it doesn't have one of these options, then I am guessing it defaults to a storage drawer. I have seen enough broilers and warmer down there though to say, it _is_ quite normal.

Answer (score 2):

Only some 30" ranges (the technical term for an oven with an integrated cooktop) have actual warming drawers, generally only high-end models. Most only have a storage drawer, one that for efficiency reasons should be well insulated from the oven proper and so isn't suitable for warming foods. A warming drawer will have its own heat source with dedicated controls.

I think most Americans would expect a 30" range and wouldn't expect an actual warming drawer. It probably wouldn't make a big difference either way, but a few might be put off if they think can't cook a huge turkey, even if they never will.

However, I'm not sure why you're concerned with future tenants. If you're renting the space then just get the range you want. Stick the old range back in when you move out and sell yours.

If on the other hand you own the space and will be renting it out in the future than I don't think what your tenants would expect should be a priority. The range you get for your renters should be cheap and easy to maintain. They will not treat it well and if it breaks it's your problem. In particular don't get a range with a glass top as these require level a care you can't really expect from a renter.

Comment: Why the diss'n of renters, most renters look after things just the way owners would. There are bad eggs in renter and owners!

Comment: @TFD I'm not trying to take sides, but it's a story I've heard before. New landlord does up unit all nice the way they'd want it, and ends up regretting not taking a utilitarian view on renovations.

Comment: The OP is in New York; I doubt there's space to save the old range for later. But agreed, Americans would be fairly surprised to see the double 24" oven, especially since it takes up extra space!

Comment: Hey now, I treat my landlord's appliances with great care. If I break my appliances, *I'm* the one with broken appliances!

Comment: @JasonC Unfortunately most landlords can't depend on their tenants seeing their appliances in the same light you do. For what it's worth, when I rented I like to think I treated the appliances well too, but I'd be naive to think I was the average tenant.